# When is cellForRowAtIndexPath called?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a tableview in my app...The contents of this list view are displayed based on ext API dynamic search...

e.g. If I type "G" in searchbar it will display GA, GB, GC1, GC2, GC3,..

if I now change to GC, it will only display GC1, GC2, GC3..

I am storing the items in an array..

My question is how do I ensure that what the user is typing and seeing as search results are synchronized..I mean if he clicks on GC1 in list view, he should see GC1's detail and not other's..

Also when is cellForRowAtIndexPath called so that I can update the array each time user types in searchbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be updating your array of filtered items in the `filterContentForSearchText: scope:` method. There is another method, `searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString` that will be called when the user types in the search bar. If you return YES from this method, then the table will be reloaded, which causes `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to be called.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of this.

Comment: It would completely depend on your filtering methods and what you are using to store your results... but just re-filter in filterContentForSearchText; and it should work fine... if you're having more troubles, post your code and specify what doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

-cellForRowAtIndexPath: is sent by the table anytime it wants a cell to display, such as when the table is redrawn, or when a new cell is needed because the user scrolled a bit.

You can force the table to update its contents by calling [table reloadData], if 'table' is a pointer to your table.

Comment: So if I need to manually call cellForRowAtIndexPath, I need to actually say [table reloadData]

is that correct?

Comment: You shouldn't call -cellForRowAtIndexPath: yourself -- the table will call it as necessary. But yes, if the content of your table changes, such as when the user changes the search term, you should call -reloadData on the table to ask the table to load a new set of cells.

Comment: If he's using a searchBar and searchDisplayController, then there's no need to call reloadData... shouldReloadTableForSearchString: will handle it for him.

Comment: Depending on how things are set up calling [table reloadData] can be expensive. (It's never hideously expensive, as only the cells to be displayed do a lot of work, but, for e.g., the delegate method tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: is called once for every row regardless of whether they are going to be displayed right away when you call reloadData). So it's worth remembering you can also use: reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: to selectively reload rows.

Comment: I agree, Gendolkari, and +1 for suggesting the right way to update if there's a search controller. I was thinking more of the general sense.